# An integral involving Riemann xi function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $z(t)$ and $w(t)$ be some complex functions of the real variable $t$ with $z(t)$ tending to some complex number as $t \rightarrow  1$ and $w(t)$ tending to $0$ as $t \rightarrow1$  I'm looking at an integral of the Riemann xi-function of the following form $\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\xi(z(t)+1-t+w(t)e^{i \theta})|d\theta$ and I would like to compare it to
$\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\xi(z(t)+w(t)e^{i \theta})|d\theta$.
If we use $\omega(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2\pi^2 n^4 x^2-3\pi n^2 x)e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ then $\xi(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\omega(x)x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}dx$. So

$\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\xi(z(t)+1-t+w(t)e^{i \theta})|d\theta=\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\omega(x)x^{\frac{z(t)+1-t+w(t)e^{i \theta}}{2}-1}dxd\theta=\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\omega(x)x^{\frac{z(t)+w(t)e^{i \theta}}{2}-1} x^{\frac{1-t}{2}}dxd\theta$

Now, $\lim_{t \to 1}x^{\frac{1-t}{2}}=1$. So is it possible to pass the limit inside the integral just for $x^{\frac{1-t}{2}}$ that is to say $\lim_{t \to 1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\xi(z(t)+1-t+w(t)e^{i \theta})|d\theta=\lim_{t \to 1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\xi(z(t)+w(t)e^{i \theta})|d\theta$?

Comment: With $z(t)$ and $w(t)$ completely unspecified, why would either one of the limits exist?

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The function $\xi$ is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function#Definition) and hence continuous. Therefore and because $w(t)\to0$ and $z(t)\to a$ for some complex $a$ (as $t\to1$), we have $\xi(z(t)+1-t+w(t)e^{i \theta})\to\xi(a)$ and $\xi(z(t)+w(t)e^{i \theta})\to\xi(a)$ uniformly in $\theta$. So, both limits in question are $2\pi|\xi(a)|$.

Comment: Thanks! I made my question too easy by forgetting some log's and being imprecise about the values of z(t) and w(t)

Comment: @Alexis : I am not sure how to understand your comment. Does this answer answer your question?